# Show Manager Name instead of Manager Id in Sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query

```
     create table Emp(empId int primary key, EmpName varchar(50),MngrID int)

insert into Emp(empId,EmpName,MngrID)values(1,'A',2)
insert into Emp(empId,EmpName,MngrID)values(2,'B',null)

create table Mngr(MngrId int primary key, MngrName varchar(50))

insert into Mngr(MngrId,MngrName)values(1,'m1')
insert into Mngr(MngrId,MngrName)values(2,'m2')
```

I want to fetch the record in Emp table for MngrId Column that show the name of Manger instead of MngrId.

sql fiddle [My fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efbfc/4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join.

```
select e.empId, e.EmpName, m.MngrName
from Emp e
inner join Mngr m on m.MngrId = e.MngrID
```